# Функция доната если присутствуют материалы под лицензии NonCommercial

Tags: android, лицензирование

В приложении андроид использую материалы которые защищены лицензии

[«Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike» («Атрибуция-Некоммерчески-СохранениеУсловий») 3.0 Непортированная (CC BY-NC-SA 3.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.ru)

Могу ли яспользовать функционал возможности доната в приложении?